# Store session in node.js

Tags: node.js, web-deployment, express-session

I want to store session in the addtocart function ad below

```
 module.exports.additemtocart = function(req, res, next) {
  var result =(req.query.domainvalue);

    req.session.cartItem = result;

}
```

After that when I go to cart menu the session destroy automatically.

```
  module.exports.cart = function(req,res) {
      var domain = req.session;
      console.log(domain);
    }
    Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',

     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true,
     cart: [] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this solution but I think you need to call the function "next" to pass the control to the next middleware function.

```
module.exports.additemtocart = function(req, res, next) {
    var result =(req.query.domainvalue);
    req.session.cartItem = result;
    next();
}
```